# render a partial on button click using jquery in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application i have form for adding education details for user.
i have form.html.erb partial in my seeker/educations/form.html.erb folder.
i want this partial to be rendered on button click, but its not working.and i have written this code inside of my form.html.erb partial so that i can call the same partial

```
 <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#addform").click(function(){
                  $('#p').html('<%= escape_javascript(render "seeker/educations/form") %>');
              });
          });
        </script>
```

this is the error message i am getting

SystemStackError in Seeker::EducationsController#new

stack level too deep

Extracted source (around line #79):

```
rescue Exception
  cleanup!
  raise
end

def prepare! #:nodoc:
```

Comment: `but its not working` is a very vague error description.

Comment: i am getting this error => stack level too deep  SystemStackError in Seeker::EducationsController#new

Comment: consider editing your question. If you copy paste the full error message into a code block, it is probably easier for others to help you.

Comment: i want multiple educations to be added. so if user clicks on "add degree" button the same form should get rendered for adding details , that s why i have used jquery for rendering the same form again,is it possible ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it by:

```
$('#p').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "seeker/educations/form") %>');
```